# How to have Jenkins pickup JUnit test reports automatically?

Tags: jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Currently I have to configure Jenkins to do a post-build task to publish the JUnit test by specifying the location of the surefile reports.

The problem is that if the project doesn't have any test, Jenkins will complain that no xml report found and fails the build.

I have seen some jenkins where people doesn't need to configure this post-build task at all and Jenkins still display graph like Test Trend ...

Does anyone has any idea how to make Jenkins pickup the surefile report automatically without having to configure it in the job? Thanks.